# Definition Schwarz Function : Which sense to give to a polynomial of R^d ? and relation with multi-indexes generalization

Tags: polynomials, notation, schwartz-space

In most of definitions , but we can take the example of Wikipedia EN of Schwartz space, people use the terminology of "monomial" or "polynomial" (depending of if we take a sum or just the sup) to refer to the "$x^\alpha$" term , but i don't understand how this terminology can be used.
R^d(d>1) is not even a field , how can we talk about a polynomial or monomial for terms of R^d ?
I looked for the meaning of the multi-index notation $x^\alpha$ ,I get it , but that doesn't relate to a "polynomial" to me.
Can someone explain , or ask me to be more clear if you don't get the question,

Comment: For example, $x^{2}y^{3}$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$. This is written as $(x,y)^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha =(2,3)$. A polynomial in $x1,x_2,..,x_d$ is a finite linear combination of functions of the type $x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}...x_n^{n_d}$ where $n_i$'are non-negative integers.

Comment: Oh i see , it is a generalization of the case R[X,Y]  ≈  (R[X])[Y] for d dimensionnal spaces i believe, thanks